# equivalence of determinants

Tags: matrices, determinant

Could someone explain to me why these two determinants are equivalent?

1)
$$\left|\begin{array}{ccc}
x-a_1 & y-a_2 & z-a_3 \\
v_1 & v_2 & v_3 \\
w_1 & w_2 & w_3
\end{array}\right|=0$$

and

$$\left|\begin{array}{cccc}
x & y & z & 1 \\
a_1 & a_2 & a_3 & 1 \\
v_1 & v_2 & v_3 & 0 \\
w_1 & w_2 & w_3 & 0
\end{array}\right|=0$$

2)
$$\left|\begin{array}{ccc}
x-a_1 & y-a_2 & z-a_3 \\
b_1-a_1 & b_2-a_2 & b_3-a_3 \\
c_1-a_1 & c_2-a_2 & c_3-a_3
\end{array}\right|=0$$

and

$$\left|\begin{array}{cccc}
x & y & z & 1 \\
a_1 & a_2 & a_3 & 1 \\
b_1 & b_2 & b_3 & 1 \\
c_1 & c_2 & c_3 & 1
\end{array}\right|=0 $$

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For 1), if you subtract the first row from the second, you obtain
$$\begin{vmatrix}x & y & z & 1 \\
a_1 & a_2 & a_3 & 1 \\
v_1 & v_2 & v_3 & 0 \\
w_1 & w_2 & w_3 & 0\end{vmatrix} = \begin{vmatrix}x & y & z & 1 \\
a_1 - x & a_2 - y & a_3 - z & 0 \\
v_1 & v_2 & v_3 & 0 \\
w_1 & w_2 & w_3 & 0\end{vmatrix}$$
Then you use the Laplace expansion wrt the last column to see
$$\begin{vmatrix}x & y & z & 1 \\
a_1 - x & a_2 - y & a_3 - z & 0 \\
v_1 & v_2 & v_3 & 0 \\
w_1 & w_2 & w_3 & 0\end{vmatrix} = 
\begin{vmatrix}
a_1 - x & a_2 - y & a_3 - z \\
v_1 & v_2 & v_3 \\
w_1 & w_2 & w_3\end{vmatrix}.$$
Finally, multiply the first row by $(-1)$ to get your result. This changes the determinant by $-1$, but will not change the fact if it is $0$ or not.

Part 2) works mostly the same, but you have to subtract the second row from all three remaining rows. Try this yourself!

Comment: For 2), shouldn’t it be the second row that we subtract?

Comment: @Ronald Good catch! I corrected this.